# How does the swimming pool in Dubai Airport's Terminal 3 work?

Tags: dubai, dxb, swimming

Have a 5h stop in Dubai. I was wondering if I have enough time to have a nice swim at the swimming pool in Dubai International Hotel/Health Club. Has anyone ever tried it? Does it include towels or do you have to pack the whole wet mess in your bag ? The jacuzzi is separated for gents and ladies, is this one too?

Comment: Just for the record (1) you have PLENTY of time, (2) they ABSOLUTELY have towels, etc - private shower rooms, (3) it's about 20 bucks per half hour.  Fantastic!!!

Comment: Yes, by all means phone them up. They are very helpful.  If you ever want to stay there, I strongly recommend ***just phoning them to book***.  No discounts at all are available, so you might as well phone to make it easier. And importantly they will take all your information like arriving/departing flights to make it a breeze for you.  ***AND*** they will walk you from the gate, see below.

Answer (score 10):

Just for the record to put in an answer:

1) it's part of the (fantastic) (confusingly named) "Dubai International Hotel" which is literally absolutely right in the airport - literally next door to the many shops.

It's in the "G-Force spa" which is part of the hotel.

2) You simply walk in and pay about 20 bucks, and you can use the pool. It's that simple. Anyone can do it.

3) You will have plenty of time with the connection you describe

4) They absolutely have huge numbers of towels, etc, laid-on - indeed the shower rooms are completely private.  Bring nothing except yourself.

Tip: it is somewhat tricky to **find the hotel**!  I have luckily stayed there often and every single time, I simply have to ask someone how to get to it. (I still can't find it!)  Very simply, **ask someone** how to get to the "Dubai International Hotel" or the "Hotel inside the airport by the shops", ask any staff member or person in a uniform, or shop person, so you can head straight there.

Enjoy!

Article about the pool with photo - [article](http://www.arabiangazette.com/5-cool-things-to-do-at-dubai-airport-20141101/)

---

Three tips regarding the hotel specifically:  (1) You can very much take a room by the **hour**, starting any time, around the clock.  It is somewhat common to suffer a long stopver - say, 10 or so hours - in DXB.  No matter what time of day this happens, you can take a room for say "7 hours" at this fantastic and unusual hotel.  (2) At no extra cost whatsoever (above the staggering room price!), the staff are absolutely happy to ***meet you as you come off your arriving plane***.  It's a huge tip. Simply phone them ahead and ask them to do this. You will be shattered from the long flight to Dubai. They will help you with everything, rush you through security and the like, and take you instantly to your glorious room where you can fall asleep immeditely in the very high thread-count sheets. I do this every time, because I still can never find the hotel, the entrance is "tucked away" behind certain shops! (3) It's the sort of hotel it's best to just pick up the phone and call them to book. No discounts are available online; and you need to give them all the info on your flights, etc, so they can serve you best, and indeed choose which "hourly rate" approach is the best deal for you. So just phone for convenience. They are ridiculously helpful.

Comment: "At no extra cost whatsoever (above the staggering room price!), the staff are absolutely happy to meet you as you come off your arriving plane." - Is this from the guy who says just suck it up in your middle seat in Y? How about just sucking it up and sleeping on a bench instead? :)

Comment: Heh - the thing is, walking around shopping for 8 hours at dxb, or just having a coffee at mcdonalds, is so overpriced you're probably better in the hotel!